# Web Crawlling A Site made in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/         click on the link to see the site

I want to download a file from a site made in Angularjs. On first page there are 6 links which I have to crawl one by one. Selecting any link will lead to a page having 3 Dropdown.

1. Select District from dropdown which lead to related talukas in second dropdown.
2. Select Taluka from dropdown which lead to related Villages in third dropdown.
3. Select Village.

Now there is radio buttons from which I have to select the one which has survey number.

Now have to insert some digits and Click on Button. Now on the same page a dropdown will be shown from which I have to select all the options one by one and Click on button, the related file will get downloaded in pop up, so have to allow popups.

Code I have done is in selenium. I have just Clicked on the link on first page and traversed to second but now have to select dropdown but dont know how to do this as this site used Angularjs

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver1.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    final NgWebDriver ngDriver;
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String baseUrl = "https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/";

    // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("अमरावती")).click();
```

Comment: OK. Nice. But you haven't asked any question.

Comment: Yes I need help to code this. I have used selenium to click the link on first page and go to second but now don't know how to select dropdown as this site uses Angularjs. Help me please.

Comment: Updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing special about this being built with AngularJS.  You don't show what you've tried after clicking on the link from the first page, so i'm guessing that you just need some guidance of what to do next.

If you inspect the new page, you'll see that there is a "select" webElement that you need to interact with.  (be sure to use WebDriverWait to wait for the control to be available).  There is a convenience class for interacting with these elements:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Here's the first dropdown:

```
dist_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('distSelect'))
select.select_by_value('string:5')
```

Comment: Error is coming for distSelect as Invalid Character constant

Comment: could you include the code that generates this error in your question above?  along with the specific error?

Comment: dist_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('distSelect')) Error -distSelect as Invalid Character constant